# Raw byte values vs Unicode text?

Tags: python-3.x, unicode, byte

I am a beginner in python and came across a chapter, which read :

In Python 3.X, the normal str string handles Unicode text (including ASCII, which is just a simple kind of Unicode); a distinct bytes string type represents raw byte values (including media and encoded text);

I understand what is unicode text, but what values are the raw bytes??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Raw bytes can be anything you want them to be.  A single byte is limited to 0-255 (hexadecimal 00-FF) so more than one has to be interpreted by a program to something meaningful.

Given the byte string `b'\x41\x42\x43\x44'`, this could be a little-endian integer:

```
>>> int.from_bytes(raw,'little')
1145258561
>>> hex(int.from_bytes(raw,'little'))
'0x44434241'
```

Or a big-ending integer:

```
>>> hex(int.from_bytes(raw,'big'))
'0x41424344'
```

Or a UTF-8-encoded Unicode string:

```
>>> raw.decode('utf8')
'ABCD'
```

Or two little-endian 16-bit unsigned integers:

```
>>> struct.unpack('HH',raw)
(16961, 17475)
>>> list(map(hex,struct.unpack('HH',raw)))
['0x4241', '0x4443']
```

It's just data.  It's up to a program decide what the data means.

Byte strings can be transmitted across a TCP socket or read or written to a file.  Unicode text cannot.  It must be encoded to bytes first.

Comment: If so, can the media and encoded text, not be handled by Unicode text ?

Comment: *Encoded* text is bytes.  *Decoded* text is Unicode.  You can only store bytes in a file (media or otherwise) and must know the encoding to decode it to Unicode text after being read.

Comment: @Sarang See http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html and http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html for more explanations of the difference.

Comment: Thanks a lot for prompt response and sharing the links !